# WebScript for uploading files: during the first upload one extra version created

Tags: java, file-upload, alfresco, versioning, alfresco-webscripts

To upload files to the repository, I use the following Java-backed WebScript:

```
public class CustomFileUploader extends DeclarativeWebScript {
    private static final String FIRM_DOC = "{http://www.firm.com/model/content/1.0}doc";
    private static final String FIRM_DOC_FOLDER = "workspace://SpacesStore/8caf07c3-6aa9-4a41-bd63-404cb3e3ef0f";

    private FileFolderService fileFolderService;
    private ContentService contentService;
    private NodeService nodeService;
    private SearchService searchService;

    protected Map<String, Object> executeImpl(WebScriptRequest req, Status status) {
        processUpload(req);
        return null;
    }

    private void writeContent(NodeRef node, FirmFile firmFile) {
        try {
            ContentWriter contentWriter = contentService.getWriter(node, ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT, true);
            contentWriter.setMimetype(firmFile.getFileMimetype());
            contentWriter.putContent(firmFile.getFileContent().getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private NodeRef checkIfNodeExists(String fileName) {
        StoreRef storeRef = new StoreRef(StoreRef.PROTOCOL_WORKSPACE, "SpacesStore");
        ResultSet resultSet = searchService.query(storeRef, SearchService.LANGUAGE_LUCENE/*LANGUAGE_FTS_ALFRESCO*/, 
                "TYPE:\"firm:doc\" AND @cm\\:name:" + fileName.replaceAll(" ", "\\ ")+ "");

        int len = resultSet.length();
        if(len == 0) { 
            return null;
        }

        NodeRef node = resultSet.getNodeRef(0);
        return node;
    }

    private NodeRef createNewNode(FirmFile firmFile) {
        NodeRef parent = new NodeRef(FIRM_DOC_FOLDER);
        NodeRef node = createFileNode(parent, firmFile.getFileName());

        return node;
    }

    private void processUpload(WebScriptRequest req) {
        FormData formData = (FormData) req.parseContent();
        FormData.FormField[] fields = formData.getFields();

        for(FormData.FormField field : fields) {
            String fieldName = field.getName();
            if(fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("firm_file") && field.getIsFile()) {
                String fileName = field.getFilename();
                Content fileContent = field.getContent();
                String fileMimetype = field.getMimetype();

                NodeRef node = checkIfNodeExists(fileName);

                // POJO
                FirmFile firm = new FirmFile(fileName, fileContent, fileMimetype, FIRM_DOC);
                if(node == null) {
                    node = createNewNode(firmFile);
                } 

                writeContent(node, firmFile);
            }
        }
    }

    private NodeRef createFileNode(NodeRef parentNode, String fileName) {
        try {
            QName contentQName = QName.createQName(FIRM_DOC);
            FileInfo fileInfo = fileFolderService.create(parentNode, fileName, contentQName);
            return fileInfo.getNodeRef();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public FileFolderService getFileFolderService() {
        return fileFolderService;
    }

    public void setFileFolderService(FileFolderService fileFolderService) {
        this.fileFolderService = fileFolderService;
    }

    public ContentService getContentService() {
        return contentService;
    }

    public void setContentService(ContentService contentService) {
        this.contentService = contentService;
    }

    public NodeService getNodeService() {
        return nodeService;
    }

    public void setNodeService(NodeService nodeService) {
        this.nodeService = nodeService;
    }

    public SearchService getSearchService() {
        return searchService;
    }

    public void setSearchService(SearchService searchService) {
        this.searchService = searchService;
    }
}
```

This WebScript works.

There is one problem: if the uploaded file does not exist in the repository, then two versions are created at once: `1.0` and `1.1`. Version `1.0` has a size of `0` bytes and has no content.

I think version `1.0` is created here:

```
FileInfo fileInfo = fileFolderService.create(parentNode, fileName, contentQName);
```

Version `1.1`, perhaps, is created here, when writing the content:

```
ContentWriter contentWriter = contentService.getWriter(node, ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT, true);
contentWriter.setMimetype(firmFile.getFileMimetype());
contentWriter.putContent(firmFile.getFileContent().getInputStream());
```

How to prevent the creation of "empty" version `1.0`?

Answer (score 5):

[Axel Faust](https://community.alfresco.com/people/afaust) gave an excellent answer to this question [here](https://community.alfresco.com/message/835303-webscript-for-uploading-files-during-the-first-upload-one-extra-version-created#comment-835307).

The problem was in the `fileuploader.post.desc.xml` descriptor, I didn't set [transaction level](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/references/api-wsdl-transaction.html) required to run the web script:

```
<transaction>none</transaction>
```

Thus, methods `writeContent()` and `createFileNode()` were transactional by default and each of them created its own version of the content.

I set the following:

```
<transaction>requiresnew</transaction>
```

The problem is solved. Thank you, [@Axel Faust](https://community.alfresco.com/people/afaust)!